# Comparing Statements and predicates using Truth Tables

Tags: proof-verification, predicate-logic, proof-theory

Consider the four statements:

- $∃x$ $∀y$ $p(x, y)$
- $∃y$ $∀x$ $p(x, y)$
- $∀x$ $∃y$ $p(x, y)$
- $∀y$ $∃x$ $p(x, y)$

which we call S1, S2, S3 and S4 respectively.

1. Does there exist a predicate p such that S1 and s4 are true, but S2 and s3 are false?
2. Does there exist a predicate p such that S2 and s3 are true, but S1 and s4 are false?
3. Does there exist a predicate p such that S3 and s4 are true, but S1 and s2 are false?
4. Does there exist a predicate p such that S4 is true, but s1, S2 and s3 are false?

> **Solution:**
>
> Consider the four predicates:
>
> [image]
>
> One can verify that:
>
> 1. if we take p to be p1, then S1 and S4 are true, but S2 and S3 are false
> 2. if we take p to be p2, then S2 and S3 are true, but S1 and S4 are false
> 3. if we take p to be p3, then S3 and S4 are true, but S1 and S2 are false
> 4. if we take p to be p4, then S4 is true, but S1, S2 and S3 are false

### Here are my questions:

1. Is my diagram correct (I highlighted the different sections)?

[image]

2. What is the *structure* of `p1`? *How do you **READ** this table?* Where is the **INPUT**? Where is the **OUTPUT**?
3. How does `p1` get fed into **$∃x$ $∀y$ $p(x, y)$**?
4. How can I come up with `p1`?
5. What is the significance of the row with #2 (highlighted in blue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the "matrix" : $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ as interpretations for the predicate letter $p$ that is $T/F$ according to the values assigned to the variables $x$ and $y$ respectively, where the values of $x$ must be read on the left and the values of $y$ on top.

Consider e.g. $S_1 : ∃x ∀y p(x,y)$, and consider the matrix $p_1$.

Is it true that there is a value for $x$ such that $p(x,y)$ is $T$ for all values for $y$ ?

> YES. Consider $p_1(0,y)$: it is $T$ for both values : $0,1$ for $y$.

Thus the predicate $p_1$ satisfy the formula $S_1$.

The same for $S_4$, and these results are consistent with the solution 1: "if we take $p$ to be $p_1$, then $S_1$ and $S_4$ are true, but $S_2$ and $S_3$ are false".

---

*Note*

In principle, the approach is the same **IF** we have to read the "matrix" in the other "direction" (as suggested by you : with the values for $x$ on top and the values for $y$ on the left) : but in that case, you can see that now the *predicate* $p_1$ does not satisfy the formula $S_1$.

But in the same way, you can verify that $p_2$ satisfy $S_1$.

Comment: Ohh so I have x and y both switched, thanks for clarifying that. Now what about the row 2? What’s the significance?

Comment: @lucidgold - I presume that **you** have highlighted it ... It has no particular significance. The author of the test has decided to design 4 different models (the $p_i$s) based on a common domain of 6 couples...